# VS 2015 Task runner explore and Resharper build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer, resharper-2016

I have a small problem I hope someone have an idea how to solve.
I have a setup where I wan't the Task runner explore to execute a gulp taser after a build. This is working fine when using VS to build. But I would like to switch to ReSharper build. But this build dosen't trigger the after build Gulp tasks

I could use resharper to define what should always be build. But then the project is depending on ReSharper and I would like to avoid this.

Anyone know if I can do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are talking about such [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458600). Right now, it is not possible.